# Does deep nesting flexbox layout cause performance issue?

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have been working on a ReactJS project where I create most of the components using flexbox layout. Since with react, we can have deeply nested components, so my layout is having nested flexbox layout.

Now my question is, does this have any issue with performance? On a single page, there are many components and each component have 3 to 4 level nested flexbox layout. Will that cause a performance issue?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Have done a little test. Rendered 100 components, each with 10 nested layout. With and without flexbox. Here are the code snippets:

**Component/index.js**

```
@CSSModules(styles, { allowMultiple: true })
export default class TheComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { deepNest, flex } = this.props

    return (
      <div>{ this.renderComp(deepNest, flex) }</div>
    )
  }

  renderComp(deepNest, flex) {
    const flexProperties = [
      { justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" },
      { justifyContent: "flex-start", alignItems: "flex-end" },
      { flexDirection: "row" }
    ]

    const content = [
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus interdum quis ligula vel elementum. Integer non rhoncus purus, eget dignissim ante.",
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.",
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus interdum quis ligula vel elementum. Integer non rhoncus purus, eget dignissim ante. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus interdum quis ligula vel elementum. Integer non rhoncus purus, eget dignissim ante."
    ]

    if (deepNest > 0 && flex) {
      return (
        <div styleName="containerFlex" style={flexProperties[deepNest % 3]}>
          <div styleName="contentFlex" style={flexProperties[deepNest % 3]}>
            { content[deepNest % 3] }
          </div>
          <div styleName="nestedFlex" style={flexProperties[deepNest % 3]}>
            { this.renderComp(deepNest - 1, flex) }
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }

    if (deepNest > 0 && !flex) {
      return (
        <div styleName="container">
          <div styleName="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus interdum quis ligula vel elementum. Integer non rhoncus purus, eget dignissim ante.
          </div>
          <div styleName="nested">
            { this.renderComp(deepNest - 1, flex) }
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
}
```

**WithFlex/index.js**

```
import TheComponent from "../Component"

@CSSModules(styles, { allowMultiple: true })
export default class WithFlex extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { render: false }
  }

  render() {
    const {render} = this.state

    // number of components to render
    const arr = _.range(100)

    return (
      <div>
        <div
        style={{ display: "block", padding: 30, lineHeight: "60px" }}
        onClick={() => this.setState({render: !render})}>
            Start Render
        </div>

        { render && arr.map((i) => <TheComponent key={i} deepNest={10} flex={true}/> ) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**WithoutFlex/index.js**

```
import TheComponent from "../Component"

@CSSModules(styles, { allowMultiple: true })
export default class WithoutFlex extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { render: false }
  }

  render() {
    const {render} = this.state

    // number of components to renders
    const arr = _.range(100)

    return (
      <div>
        <div
        style={{ display: "block", padding: 30, lineHeight: "60px" }}
        onClick={() => this.setState({render: !render})}>
            Start Render
        </div>

        { render && arr.map((i) => <TheComponent key={i} deepNest={10} flex={false}/> ) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

### Results from Chrome dev-tool timeline.

**WithFlex**

[image]

**WithoutFlex**

[image]

### Summary

The difference is not that much. Also in flexbox, I put random properties to choose from. So I think it's alright with the performance. Hope it will help other devs.

Comment: this is some great info, however wouldn't it be more accurate if you used straight html instead of printing html out of a js script?

Comment: @Brian Yes, you're right. My problem was actually while working with react. That's why rendered the components with react.

Comment: Looking just at the render time of your charts I would say that flex takes 3 times the time.

Answer (score 6):

Old flexbox (display: box) is 2.3x slower than new flexbox (display: flex).
Regular block layout (non-float), will usually be as fast or faster than new flexbox since it’s always single-pass. But new flexbox should be faster than using tables or writing custom JS-base layout code.
For more info
[Article1](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/building-the-new-financial-times-web-app-a-case-study/)
[Article2](https://css-tricks.com/does-flexbox-have-a-performance-problem/)