# Make nested children 100% height of variable height container without flexbox

Tags: html, css

I have a bunch of nested lists inside a variable height container, and I'd like all of the nested lists/children to take up 100% height of the container.

I have tried using flexbox, which works in principle, but with around 5-6 nested lists (of which all have display: flex; and flex-direction: column;) I'm noticing huge performance issues in Chrome, FF and Safari when adding more nested lists programmatically (too many reflows maybe?) so I can't use flexbox in this case. I've also not been able to get it to work using table and table-cell.

A very simple example here: https://jsfiddle.net/bf0f6zj5/

The markup:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      text 1
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          some very long text here
        </div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <div>
              text 3
            </div>
            <ul>
              <li>text</li>
              <li>text</li>
              <li>text</li>
              <li>text</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
ul, li {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow:hidden;
}

li {
  border-left: 1px solid grey;
  padding-left: 8px;
}

li > div {
  padding-right: 4px;
  float:left;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
}
```

The goal is to make the left borders of the nested lists the same height as the largest one, without using flexbox.

Edit: Created a new fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vgjkzhqq/3/ to show the performance problems I'm having with flexbox (notice how long it takes to render - over 2000ms for me)

Edit 2: pasted wrong link

Comment: First off all, you need to actually define 100% height.

Comment: By container, do you mean the `ul`?

Comment: 100% height doesn't do much here, as the parent (the outermost ul) doesn't have a fixed height

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is not causing performance problems, according to a lot of different sources, including Google Web developpers :

- [Flexbox layout isn't slow - Google Developpers](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/10/Flexbox-layout-isn-t-slow)
- [Does deep nesting flexbox layout cause performance issue? - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39463220/does-deep-nesting-flexbox-layout-cause-performance-issue)
- [Use flexbox over older layout models - Google Developpers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/rendering/avoid-large-complex-layouts-and-layout-thrashing#use_flexbox_over_older_layout_models)

### TL;DR

Flexbox is usually faster than older display properties. As [Paul](https://developers.google.com/web/resources/contributors#paulirish) says:

> Old flexbox (display: box) is 2.3x slower than new flexbox (display: flex)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: I have created a new fiddle to show the performance problems: https://jsfiddle.net/vgjkzhqq/
It's taking over 2000ms to render